# Material UI Checkbox on or off?

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, material-ui

When I use a Metrial UI Checkbox (React Material UI Checkbox component, replaces a standard checkbox form element). How would I tell using Webdriver or similar browser controller if its on or off? or more specifically what is the recommended way? I could add an event listener and add an on/off type attribute. But is there a better out of the box way? Obviously the props change but that is not available to webdriver, I guess adding an attribute based on the prop would work but trying to avoid that. Below is the output available to webdriver in my code. Hoping for help from someone with webdriver and "material ui checkbox react component" experience to offer some insights.

```
<div class="checkbox-0-61">
   <div style="cursor: pointer; position: relative; overflow: visible; display: table; height: auto; width: 100%;">
      <!-- react-empty: 92 --><input type="checkbox" value="on" style="position: absolute; cursor: inherit; pointer-events: all; opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2; left: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
      <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
         <div style="transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; float: left; position: relative; display: block; flex-shrink: 0; width: 24px; margin-right: 16px; margin-left: 0px; height: 24px;">
            <div>
               <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: rgb(0, 114, 234); height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: opacity 650ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 150ms; position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                  <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
               </svg>
               <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: rgb(0, 114, 234); height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: opacity 0ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms, transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; position: absolute; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);">
                  <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
               </svg>
            </div>
            <div><span style="height: 200%; width: 200%; position: absolute; top: -12px; left: -12px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none; color: rgb(0, 114, 234);"></span></div>
            <div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <label style="float: left; position: relative; display: block; width: calc(100% - 60px); line-height: 24px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54); font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;">My Checkbox</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `Metrial UI Checkbox`? `the value doesn't change` which attribute value of which element?

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB added more info for you.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC added my thoughts and attempts to fix.

Comment: It is still not clear why you are emphasizing on `Metrial UI Checkbox`. For `Selenium` a checkbox is a checkbox and `Selenium` would be able to interact with it just like a human. Can you update the question with you exact `Manual Steps` you are trying to `Automate`?

Comment: I may have been overthinking it turns out http://webdriver.io/api/state/isSelected.html works just fine also if you target the input inside the Mui checkbox component. `browser.isSelected('.muiCheckboxSelector input');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript

```
public boolean isChecked(WebElement element) {
    return (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].checked", element);
}
```

Comment: I do not know what language you use. This solution is Java-based.